# How to get sms sender id/number android

Tags: android, sms-retriever-api

I am using SMS Retriever API for auto fill OTP. As I want to show up auto otp dialog for particular sender id only.But I am stuck at capturing sender's id/number. Can someone help me to get that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/user-consent/request

Comment: If you are passing the sender id .. why do you want to know the sender id from SMS? its already known info to you